# How to make IonViewDidLoad run AFTER event subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Hi I am passing a data from page1 to page2 in ionic using events.

In page 2, I use the code below to subscribe to the data that was passed from page 1.

```
events.subscribe('restoProfile:selected', (restoData) => {
        this.restoData = restoData;
        console.log(this.restoData);
      });
```

The `console.log` on the line above works correctly by displaying the data on the console log.

The problem is, I am using the `this.restoData` for another function in `IonViewDidLoad`, but this function says that the content inside `this.restoData` is undefined.

I tried to add a button which calls `console.log(this.restoData)` and the content inside `this.restoData` is logged correctly.

I suppose the `IonViewDidLoad` runs before the event is subscribed.

How can I make IonViewDidLoad to run **AFTER** the event is subscribed?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You cant.. You will have to run the logic in event subscription

Comment: Man thank you! Why didn't I thought about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you aim to accomplish, a bit of code would help.

I guess that there is some inconsistency when the event fires and the second page is being loaded.

I don't know if this is applicable to your case, but I would have a `restoData provider` let's say - if this is a set of data that get retrieved and change frequently, otherwise a `data.provider` with an initialised  member `restoData: Resto[] = []` (or any).

When firing the event you mutate the data on the provider, and when you visit the page, you have already injected the provider (which is imported only in the app.module.ts, hence 1 instance) and display directly the data coming from the provider.

Comment: Thanks George. Yes I created a provider, and put the logic inside it. Then I call the provider right after `this.restoData = restoData`.

Answer (score 1):

instead of doing that you can create a function "runthefunctionyouwant" put the code that you want to execute and put the event inside the ionviewdidload. after the event subscribe call the function "runthefunctionyouwant" after passing the restodata to "this.restoData"

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
    events.subscribe('restoProfile:selected', (restoData) => {
            this.restoData = restoData;
            console.log(this.restoData);
            this.runTheFunctionYouWant();
});
}

runTheFunctionYouWant(){
//code that you want to run
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Yeah man. That can also work. In my case, I put the function inside a provider. Thanks for your help.